# How to only current date enable in input date type in C# or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, date, webforms

I am trying enable only current date but disable future dates. Please help me.

Ny code:

```cs
txtshiftdate.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

ASPX Code:

```html
<asp:TextBox type="date" TabIndex="3" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txtshiftdate" />
```

Comment: Some more code would be appreciated. What type is the txtshifdate object? Guessing based on this description I'd say you need to replace "min" with "max".

Comment: i want to only current date enable code in c# or javascript

Comment: What's the point of having an input if the only date you can enter is today's date?

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes

Comment: i want to html input datepicker enable only today date

Comment: Why? There's no point. You know what day it is. The user knows what day it is. Why do you need the user to tell you what day it is?

Comment: current day only enable in datepicker

Comment: because shift only assign current day  so current date only enable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a date that is entered in the textbox is within a certain range, you should write the validation code in the OnTextChanged handler for example:

```
<asp:TextBox ... OnTextChanged="txtshiftdate_TextChanged">
```

In the handler, you should parse the input and change it for to the corrected value if necessary.

```
protected void txtshifdate_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    txtshiftdate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: i want to direct enable only today date in html datepicker